# Turtlebot teleop running, no response

Tags: ros, turtlebot, keyboard-teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have run the following commands...

1. roscore
2. roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
3. roslaunch turtlebot_teleop keyboard_teleop.launch

Everything *appears* to be working, but when pressing different movement keys (m, n, etc.) there is no response from the TurtleBot (i.e. it is not moving).  When changing the different speeds with the e, q, etc. keys messages are being sent saying that the speeds have changed.  So, I know there is some sort of communication between the terminal and the TurtleBot.

Yes, everything is plugged in correctly and charged.

Please help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61517/turtlebot-teleop-running,-no-response/) by [mkm_marquette](https://answers.ros.org/users/4755/mkm_marquette/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-05-03**:
Do you have TurtleBot 1 or TurtleBot 2? I would check also whether something gets published on velocity  topic (rostopic echo /mobile_base/commands/velocity)

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-05-26**:
Just a side note: If you use roslaunch, you don't need to manually start up a roscore. roslaunch is doing this for you: it starts one, if it can't find a running roscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try using turtlebot dashboard. It will confirm whether communication between robot and laptop has been established correctly or not.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1